# How to resolve the 'ARCoreBase.xcframework not found' and 'Linker command failed with exit code 1' issue of outputting iOS app to iPad in Xcode15.0.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, augmented-reality, arcore

I tried to export an AR application to a tablet in the latest version of Xcode15.0.1(My iPad version is iOS16.1.1), but encountered the two issues shown in the images below.

“Showing Recent Issues
Ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lCesiumForUnityNative-Runtime', '-lc++', '-lsqlite3', '-lz'

Framework 'ARCoreBase.xcframework' not found

Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/br0nS.png)
How can I resolve them?

I tried to export an AR application to a tablet in the latest version of Xcode, but encountered the two issues and can not build successful.